# QGIS: Style Point displacement brings too much together

Tags: qgis, point

I want points which are close together, about 10 mm from each other on the printed map or 500m in real world to be arranged in a circle around their center point. In other words I use Point Displacement in Layer Properties | Style. I have played around with the point distance tolerance number (mm, pixel and map units), but if I at all allow points to be displace (>0) points from a much too large area are displaced. If I for instance use 0,5mm as the Point distance tolerance, points from at least 10km away are put together. Is there something else wrong / som other settings that I need to adjust, or what is it that I do not understand.

How it should be, with these points centered around their real place (the red star):
[image: How it should be]

How the points are shown, if I enter any number bigger than 0 in the Point displacement tolerance box (points from a point a few km away are included, and the red star is shown somewhere between these two points) :

[image: How it should not be]